# SQL Server Stored Procedure and Variables Conditional on Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Using a stored procedure in SQL Server, I am trying to place values into several conditional variables. I suspect the problem is that these variables are count/sum like values conditional on two different tables.

For example:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetTrends]
AS
DECLARE @N_NE INT
DECLARE @BB_NE
DECLARE @date DATETIME

    BEGIN
    SELECT @date = GETDATE();
        SELECT @N_NE = SUM(CASE WHEN a.STATUS = 'Active' AND b.REGION = 'NE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.STATUS = 'Ready' AND b.REGION = 'NE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        FROM dbo.FOO as a INNER JOIN dbo.BAR as b on a.ID = b.ID;
        SELECT @BB_NE = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ANOTHERTABLE
        INSERT INTO dbo.Trends (Date) VALUES (@date);
        UPDATE dbo.Trends SET N_NE = (@N_NE + @BB_NE) WHERE DATE = @date;
    END;
```

The individual `SELECT` query runs fine on its own, but when I try to `CREATE` the `PROC`, I get several errors which take this form:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure My Proc, Line 51
>   The multi-part identifier "a.STATUS" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure My Proc, Line 51
>   The multi-part identifier "b.REGION" could not be bound.

And so on...

Is there a way around this / am I making a terrible blunder?  Thanks kindly.

Comment: Instead of posting the working code maybe you could post the code that is not working?

Comment: The code above doesn't work.  However, if I take out the "@N_NE =" and run as its own query, instead of as part of a CREATE PROC, it works fine.

Comment: You really need to show the `CREATE PROCEDURE` code instead. And if the `SELECT` works on its own, then it shouldn't be throwing that error later

Comment: @user1893148 So, does the table `FOO` has a column `STATUS`?, and table `BAR` has a column `REGION`?

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question now.  And I agree it doesn't make sense to me.  And yes the referenced columns live in the referenced tables (e.g. the query works on its own).

Comment: Giv us SP declaration and body please

Comment: Why are you declaring the variables outside the `BEGIN`/`END`?. Also, not that it will throw an error, but you are not asigning a value to the `@date` variable. Did you posted the whole sp?, are you completely sure that those column are referencing the right tables?

Comment: `Procedure My Proc, Line **51**` - sure for displaying the right SP?

Comment: Bear with me.  I'm obviously not posting the original SP (which is long and repetitive).  See edits.

Comment: @user1893148 But then you are also probably not posting the error

Comment: Lamak I understand your concern: but trust me that the whole SP is just the above repeated 30 times.  There are no element types I'm leaving out.

Comment: @user1893148 sure for using the same database?

Comment: @user1893148 Then you wouldn't be getting **that** error if those columns exist on those tables. So, you are removing the error on the posted code

Comment: Using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @user1893148 i mean, the same server and database when tried with SP and direct SQL

Comment: Anyway, if direct query works well, then the problem can only be you're querying wrong table/db/server

Comment: Do you have a `;` in the end of line, just before the `FROM`?

Comment: Not possible. Post the ***actual code that fails*** not some vague representation of it from elsewhere in the procedure.

Comment: @user1893148 If the **first** error is in line 51 and for some obscure reason, you don't want to show the whole SP, it would help to show the lines nearby (say the lines from 40 to 52), exactly as they are in your SP.

Comment: Why doesn't someone explain to me why they are down voting this question.

Comment: @user1893148 temporarily remove all rest code from SP but that you shwon us and re-run. Does it produce error?

Comment: @user1893148 because even when multiple users have said to you that we need the actual code, since the current one won't throw that error, you are refusing. Hence, we can't answer because it's not a clear question

Comment: They are downvoting you because several people have wasted tens of comments and you still haven't provided the exact code that errors with the exact error you get from that. You have only posted a part of the code (which is not sure whether is working or not) and "something like" the errors you get.

Comment: @user1893148 if you put SELECT *  inside SP, does it return those columns?

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help.  I'm going a different route.  Will post if I fix it.  Sorry I couldn't post entire SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.
1. Ensure your both connections are to the same server/database
2. Stop all services that can DDL your table
3. Try direct SQL and via SP that contains **only** the same (copy/paste) query. They will return equal results.